# Show main options at the beggining of and array for Vue select list?

Tags: arrays, vuejs2, v-select

In the country select list dropdown for example, I want to show the most common selected options first, but also show them in their usual ordered-by-name position along the full array. I also plan to do this on other select for products and categories.

I'm using v-select to create the select list and was able to merge the "main options" array with concat() method:

`this.arrNew = this.arrMain.concat(this.arrCountry);`

```
data() {
    return {
      arrCountry: [],
      arrMain: [
        {"label":"Brasil","code":1},
        {"label":"Estados Unidos","code":136}
      ],
      arrNew: []
    }
  },
```

but as expected I get a Vue warn due to duplicate keys and also the countries are displayed twice at the search results of the select.

How do I combine more than one array for the select option without actually merging them?

I would also like to place dividers and text to name each array.

My component code for country select is like this:

```
<template>
<div>
  <v-select v-model="$attrs.countryName" id="country" name="country" autocomplete="off" v-validate="'required'" required class="style-select-filter" @option:selected="$emit('changed', $event)" :options="arrNew" placeholder="Selecione um país"></v-select>
  <small v-if="errors.has('country')" class="field-text is-danger">{{ errors.first('country') }}</small>
</div>
</template>
<script>

let config = {
  headers: {
  }
}

export default {
  name: "Selectcountry",
  inject: ['$validator'],
  data() {
    return {
      arrCountry: [],
      arrMain: [
        {"label":"Brasil","code":1},
        {"label":"Estados Unidos","code":136}
      ],
      arrNew: []
    }
  },  
  methods: {
    clearTest() {
      alert("Teste");
    },
    searchcountries() {
        
      this.$http.get('country/list', config).then(response => {
            
        this.arrCountry = response.data.pt;
        this.arrNew = this.arrMain.concat(this.arrCountry);

      }).catch(error => {
              console.log(error)
              this.errored = true
      }).finally(() => this.loading = false);

    }
  },
  created() {

  },
  mounted() {

      this.searchcountries();

  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was changing the id keys on arrMain from "code" to "id" so I don't get a duplicate keys warn on console. Also I added an empty label and a "text" key to name and separate the arrays.

```
data() {
    return {
      arrCountry: [],
      arrMain: [
        {"label":"","text":"Most used"},
        {"label":"Brasil","id":1},
        {"label":"Estados Unidos","id":136},
        {"label":"","text":"All"}
      ],
      arrNew: []
    }
  },
```

And then a template with a custom option prop to display the way I want:

```
<template #option="{ label, text }">
      <p style="font-weight: bold; margin: 0; pointer-events: none" class="pe-none user-select-none">{{ text }}</p>
      <span>{{ label }}</span>
</template>
```

The only thing I could not find a way to do is to block selection on the "text" keys in the dropdown. pointer-events: none; does not work.